# Find the smallest number whose digits multiply to a given number

Tags: c++, c++11

(beginner here)

My task says I have to find the smallest number whose digits multiply to a given number. If such number cannot be made output "-1"

Example:

```
10 = 25       2*5=10
13 = -1  
5 = 5     
100 = 455     4*5*5 = 100
```

input is a single number n;
0 <= n <= 10^9

My code seems to work fine, but whenever I try to upload it to a contest website my code doesn't pass all the test cases. All test cases are hidden so I don't know the specific test case my code fails.

So I wanted to ask for help, I want to know how can I find that specific test case or even better help me find that test case.

My code is based on code from these websites:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/smallest-number-k-product-digits-k-equal-n/

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-smallest-number-whose-digits-multiply-given-number-n/

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

    // function to find smallest number k such that
    // the product of digits of k is equal to n
    long long int smallestNumber(long long int n)
    {
        // if 'n' is a single digit number, then
        // it is the required number
        if (n >= 0 && n <= 9)
            return n;

        // stack the store the the digits
        stack<long long int> digits;

        // repeatedly divide 'n' by the numbers 
        // from 9 to 2 until all the numbers are 
        // used or 'n' > 1
        for (long long int i = 9; i >= 2 && n > 1; i--)
        {
            while (n % i == 0)
            {
                // save the digit 'i' that divides 'n'
                // onto the stack
                digits.push(i);
                n = n / i;
            }
        }

        // if true, then no number 'k' can be formed 
        if (n != 1)
            return -1;

        // pop digits from the stack 'digits'
        // and add them to 'k'
        long long int k = 0;
        while (!digits.empty())
        {
            k = k * 10 + digits.top();
            digits.pop();
        }

        // required smallest number
        return k;
    }

    // Driver program to test above
    int main()
    {
        long long int n;//number i want to convert
        cin >> n;
        cout << smallestNumber(n);
        return 0;
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Where is the web site with the problem? In particular, what is the **full** specification of 5he problem? What is the limit on the size of the numbers it must handle? Does it tell you which test case failed (by test case ID, not by input)? Do you know whether even one test case passed?

Comment: @MaxVollmer: [Wikipedia: Product (mathematics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(mathematics)#Product_of_sequences)  "The product of a sequence consisting of only one number is just that number itself. The product of no factors at all is known as the empty product, and is equal to 1."

Comment: if input is 5 the answer is 5, just tested in the contest system. If I make 5 = -1, I only pass 7 test instead of 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your input is 0 then it should return 10 not 0

Comment: Wow I can't believe that was the answer, thanks a bunch!